# Queue for custom objects

Tags: queue

Can we create a look-up form a custom object(Child) to another custom or standard object(Master) with cascade-delete option enabled?
If yes then can we create a queue for that custom object as queue don't support custom detail object and look-up with cascade delete behaves as master-detail?

Comment: Did you try it? Where are you stuck? What error, if any, did you receive?

Comment: No I'm not able to create a (cascade delete look-up) relationship in salesforce as I am not able to find that option. As far I know cascade-delete only enabled by salesforce not by the admin of the org. But in case of master detail the detail object is not showing in the queue. Can you please explain why it is happening?

Comment: Please use [edit] to elaborate on your question with specific example

Answer (score 2):

Custom detail objects do not have an Owner field, so it is impossible to put those type of records in to a queue. You would need to use lookup fields, then simulate cascade delete with triggers. This would allow to assign ownership, including to queues.